# read INTs from .txt in CMD (formatted txt) java

Tags: java

I have to write a program for a project. THe program itself works perfectly. But I have an additional requirement:

The programm needs to be open over the console via java MyProgramm input.txt 2 3
(This is an example input statement, where input is a txt file that contains a single number followed by pairs of two numbers(ints). Pairs are separated by a line break, numbers of the pairs are separated by space).

I need to read these numbers into an int and an int array[][] and two ints.

How can I achieve this? I already solved a similar problem where all numbers where single ints each on a new line. But here I'm stuck.

There are some solutions here, but none seems to suit my specific problem!?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: You should adapt the solutions you've found to fit your specific use case. Here's a hint: you're probably going to use a scanner (it seems that's what most students use for these homework assignments).  You should look into the method "_Scanner.nextInt()_" (and other similar methods).  Here is [the documentation for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). The answer provided by @JaneDoh is another good approach...

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Check out, `String.split();` you can use something similar to:

```
String[] str = inputLine.split(",");
```

The above would split the incoming line by commas and throw them into a string array. This isn't the answer, but similar.

Comment: +1 - but can I be picky and ask that you link to the latest docs (1.7) as it may contain more update info and possible deprecation information that we developers should be aware of...

Comment: Can do. Didn't notice that!

Comment: ... I guess it's time to start linking to Java 7 now that Java 6 is about to go bye bye :(